# perturbation of Invariant subspaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, matrices

Let $A,B$ be matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ sufficiently close in the usual metric on matrices. Suppose $A$, resp., $B$ stabilizes a $k$-dimensional subspace $U$, resp., $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $0 < k < $ dim $V$. Is there any topological relationship between $U$ and $V$? Is there any metric on the set of $k$-dimensional spaces, and if Yes can it be said that $U$ and $V$ are close in that metric?

Comment: There's no natural metric on the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Also, if $A$ is generic, then it will have $n$ distinct eigenvalues and so each of the $k$-dimensional subspaces that $A$ stabilizes will be a sum of $k$ eigenlines of $A$.  If $B$ is sufficiently close to $A$, then $B$ will also have distinct eigenvalues and the eigenlines of $B$ will be close to the eigenlines of $A$.  It's when you have multiplicities that things become unstable.

Answer (score 1):

One "natural" metric on the $k$-dimensional subspaces is the Hausdorff metric on their intersections with the unit ball.

Consider the case $A = I$.  Every $k$-dimensional subspace is invariant under $I$.  Let $C$ be a matrix with all eigenvalues distinct, and consider $B = I + t C$ for small $t$.  The subspaces invariant under $B$ are the same as the subspaces invariant under $C$, and there are only $n \choose k$ of them that are
$k$-dimensional.  In particular, you can choose a $U$ that is not one of these,
and no $V$ will be close to $U$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why B and C have the same invariant subspaces ? Thank you.

Comment: If $V$ is invariant under $C$, then for every $v \in V$, $Bv = v + t C v \in V$.  Similarly the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You should read Gohberg, Lancaster, Rodman, *Invariant subspaces with Applications*, Part III. Very detailed results are contained there.

Another good reference, more applied/numerical, is Stewart, Sun, *Matrix perturbation theory*, whose Part 2 is on invariant subspaces. It contains several closed-form bounds for the distance.

Quick TL;DR version (but go check the book anyway, there is much more there): the (semi-)natural metric to use is $\|P_U-P_V\|$, where $P_Z$ is the orthogonal projector on $Z$ and the norm is any matrix norm, usually the Euclidean one. If the eigenvalues associated to $U$ are distinct from those *not* associated to it, then the invariant subspace is Lipschitz stable under small perturbations. On the other hand, if your invariant subspace 'sees' an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $k$ of $A$ with strictly smaller multiplicity $0<k'<k$, then things become trickier (as you may expect: e.g., perturb $A=I$).

If $A$ is Hermitian, then the Lipschitz constant is the inverse of the minimum difference between these two sets of eigenvalues; if $A$ is nonsymmetric, then this Lipschitz constant (known as *separation*) can be arbitrarily worse than the spectral gap (e.g., take $\begin{bmatrix}1 & k\\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ for large $k$; its eigenvectors are very close, although the eigenvalues are separated): there is an expression for it as the solution of a matrix equation but it's often unwieldy.